# Wrong status received from "git status" command

Tags: git, gitlab

Me and my friend are sharing the same remote repository. He committed and pushed some changes to the remote. But when I use `git status` command it still shows that my local is up to date with the remote instead of showing that the remote is ahead by some commits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to fetch here:

```
git fetch origin
```

This will sync up your local Git repo with the current state of the true remote repository.  It is important to note that when you type `git status`, what you see reported for each local branch is actually determined by comparing against the local *tracking* branches for your local repository.  So, for example, if your friend made changes to, and pushed, the `master` branch, you would not immediately see it.  This is because your Git is comparing `master`, a local branch, against `origin/master`, another local branch.  To update `origin/master`, you need to do a `git fetch` first.  Then, `git status` will reflect the current state of the remote repository.